# My BE behind Apache needs to access client host, but ProxyPreserveHost does not work

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, host

I am working with Spring Boot microservices behind Apache 2.4.6 proxy on CentOS.
My microservices need to access client hostname, but I keep receiving Apache server hostname on x-forwarded-host, while the x-forwarded-for contains the correct client IP.
I edited my config adding

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

to httpd.conf (as well as sshd.conf) in the VirtualHost section, but the problem persists.
Does anyone have idea of how to help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ProxyPreserveHost` is the *server's* host name, not the client's. And there's never a guarantee that you can get anything more than the client's IP address (potentially masqueraded). Most IP addresses don't reverse-resolve a hostname. What makes you think that `sshd.conf` has anything to do here?

Comment: Thanks.
I will work just with IPs.
For what regards `sshd.conf`, I meant `ssl.conf`.